# Changing request and response with an Apache Proxy Server

Tags: apache, web-services, http, proxy, webserver

I want to use an Apache proxy server (`mod_proxy`) to intercept all requests and responses to a web server. However I want to change requests and responses before redirecting them. Simply rewriting URLs is easy and documented, but the changes I want to make are more sophisticated, namely they need to inspect the request for user credentials as well as conditionally make redirects.

Is this possible in Apache's `mod_rewrite`, possibly in combination with other modules?

While the main goal is to implement this in Apache, I would also be happy with an alternative solution which doesn't necessarily use Apache.

---

Here is a more precise explanation of what I want to achieve, to give a little more context:

- Check each incoming request for user credentials. If credentials are present, they are replaced by the user information which the web server can use to identify the user (Ideally in the `Authorization` header)
  For example, let's assume a request contains a cookie which authenticates the request as beeing sent from the user "John", this cookie is removed, and the Authorization header is changed to `Authorization Authenticated_by_proxy {"id":12345,"name":"John"}`
- Check each answer to see if it's an Error 403. If this is the case and the user is not logged in, redirect the user to a login page instead of forwarding the error

Comment: Hi Misch, were you able to implement this? If so, would you please share your solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ambal. No, I didn't find a solution and in the end I implemented a totally different solution, without using proxies.